# SUM multiple columns by different condition from same table and then group by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I tried to SUM values of multiple columns (CASH+CARD+CHEQUE+REST) and group them to display totals for each day.

Actual table:

| Date | CASH | CARD | CHEQUE | REST | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-02 | 150.00 | 200.00 | 0.00 | 12.00 | STORE1 |
| 2022-06-02 | 150.00 | 240.00 | 56.00 | 67.00 | STORE2 |
| 2022-06-02 | 45.00 | 459.00 | 150.00 | 0.00 | STORE3 |
| 2022-06-02 | 45.00 | 400.00 | 150.00 | 34.00 | TRAVEL1 |
| 2022-06-03 | 87.00 | 59.00 | 150.00 | 400.00 | STORE1 |
| 2022-06-03 | 45.00 | 790.00 | 450.00 | 104.00 | STORE2 |
| 2022-06-03 | 70.00 | 30.00 | 0.00 | 241.00 | STORE3 |
| 2022-06-03 | 30.00 | 120.00 | 11.00 | 72.00 | TRAVEL1 |

I want it to make it as new table as:

| Date | TOTAL_SALE | STORE_TOTAL | TRAVEL_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-02 | 2158.00 | 1529.00 | 629.00 |
| 2022-06-03 | 2659.00 | 2426.00 | 233.00 |

I tried with UNION but that puts the result one below other and not like this in the same row,
I also tried the option below but am getting this error

> #1111 invalid use of group function

Code I use that produces an error:

```
SELECT DATE, (SUM(CASH) + SUM(CARD) + SUM(CHEQUE) + SUM(REST)) AS TOTAL_SALE,

SUM(case when TYPE LIKE 'STORE%' then (SUM(CASH) + SUM(CARD) + SUM(CHEQUE) + SUM(REST))
else 0 end) as STORE_TOTAL,
SUM(case when TYPE LIKE 'TRAVEL%' then (SUM(CASH) + SUM(CARD) + SUM(CHEQUE) + SUM(REST))
else 0 end) as TRAVEL_TOTAL

FROM tbl_Payment where DATE BETWEEN '2022-06-02' AND '2022-06-03'
GROUP BY DATE ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `group by` does not take an order. No `asc`.

The problem is putting `sum` inside a `sum`. Whatever is inside `sum` will be summed *per row*, there's no need to sum it again.

Similarly, you don't have to sum each column and then add the sums. Add the columns then sum. This is a bit more succinct.

```
SELECT
  "DATE",
  SUM(CASH + CARD + CHEQUE + REST) AS TOTAL_SALE,
  SUM(
    case when TYPE LIKE 'STORE%' then
      CASH + CARD + CHEQUE + REST
    else
      0
    end
  ) as STORE_TOTAL,
  SUM(
    case when TYPE LIKE 'TRAVEL%' then
      CASH + CARD + CHEQUE + REST
    else
      0
    end
  ) as TRAVEL_TOTAL
FROM tbl_Payment
where "DATE" BETWEEN '2022-06-02' AND '2022-06-03'
GROUP BY "DATE"
```

Note: `date` is a SQL keyword. It can be confused with the type `date`. Avoid using it as a column name. Use the `at` and `on` conventions for naming timestamp and date columns. For example, `paid_on`.

Comment: OMG yes, I can see my mistake now and understand sum logic. Also thanks for the note on naming DATE/TIME columns. Cheers